# CMake generated Xcode project fails to find the binary "Products" that are built from Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake

I am trying to use CMake Generated Xcode project. Everything looks good when building, except that Xcode can not find the binaries that are built. Below is a screenshot i took after successfully build the product. I can see them in the project source directory. However, notice that the Xcode showing RED "HelloWorld", which means it can not find the products.

[image: Screenshot of Products not available showing Red]

Configurations: CMake 2.8.6 with Xcode 4.2 on Lion 10.7.2

This is CMakeLists.txt

```
project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} HelloWorld.cpp)
```

This is the source code for HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "HelloWorld!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a raw project directly from Xcode, after compiles, the products shows black instead of red font, which means Xcode found the products. So i am sure this is related to CMake Generated Xcode project.

Anyone got any idea? how to fix this?

Comment: Is your goal here merely to stop Xcode from rendering the product name in red, or are there other problems as well? Is Xcode unable to find the binary when you go to execute it in the debugger, for example?

Comment: It's a problem that I am experiencing. Xcode is not able to build the product if the Xcode project is generated by CMake.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes. the binary is built and I can see it in the source directory. But Xcode is not able to execute it.

Comment: I tried this myself using your CMakeLists.txt and source. The product name remained stubbornly red, but I was able to launch the program and see the output in the debugger just fine. I could even set a breakpoint and it worked. About the only thing I can think of is that when I used the CMake GUI program to generate the Xcode project the default active scheme was ZERO_CHECK, which doesn't have the HelloWorld target as a dependency so nothing gets built when it is the active scheme. I just changed the active scheme to HelloWorld and then it worked.

Comment: thanks sjs. For me, the build is set to ALL_BUILD and after I switch to HelloWorld, Xcode can execute it with break points. It looks like the only problem left is that stubborn red even if binary is produced

Answer (score 1):

The xcode project file (which I guess, in your case would be named something like `HelloWorld.xcproject/project.pbxproject`, will have SYMROOT definitions for each of the build configurations per target.

You can either change all the SYMROOT definitions to the same value or remove all of those (xcode will default to "build").

Project, if open, should autoreload. Select ALL_BUILD or HelloWord, clean and build.

Not sure if it is an issue with the way cmake adds the SYMROOT.
Note: I know this only hints at what the problem could be and not a solution but am not allowed to add comments yet :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me it was caused by an extra "build" directory in the search path Xcode was using to find the product. I hacked around the problem by putting the products in the location Xcode expects, i.e. I added the extra "build" directory.:

```
if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL Xcode)
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Debug)
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Release)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Debug)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Release)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Debug)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/Release)
endif()
```